# Reading and using Screen Coordinates from txt file

Tags: c#, text, coordinates

Heya i've been working on this project.
[Link to Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fwXNYAp2)

And i wonder if its possible to read coordinates instead from the

txtX2 , txtY2
TextBox's

but rather from a text document.

And using those Coordinates in the Text Document instead.

If you dont understand what im saying please reply :P
but if you look at the code you will probably understand.

Thanks :)

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "Text Document"?  Are you asking how to load a few pieces of information from a plain text file?

Comment: What im asking for is that when i Timer2 starts as you can see on the Code it should read the Coordinates from a plain text file instead of from the 2 text boxes named "txtX2" and "txtY2".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have saved the coordinates in a text file with the following format:

```
<Coordinate1>,<Coordinate2>
```

You can do:

```
String contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText();
String[] coordinates = contents.Split(',');
```

Now **`coordinates[0]`** is **`X`** and **`coordinates[1]`** is **`Y`**.

---

If there are multiple lines in the file and you want to read one line in each timer tick, you can actually do something like this:

```
// class variable
private StreamReader reader;

// in constructor
reader = System.IO.File.OpenText("PATH");

// in destructor
reader.close();

// in timer
String line;
if ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    String[] coordinates = line.split(',');
    // now coordinates[0] is X and coordinates[1] is Y
}
```

Comment: +1, but small typo. You create `line` then assign to and use `input`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple example of how to read from a text file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx